# Jquery DataTable Export to Excel ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, datatables, tabletools

Does anyone have an alternative solution to using TableTools for exporting Jquery's Datatable to an Excel sheet? We cannot use TableTools because it requires Flash to be enabled but since a vast majority of our clients have their Flash disabled we sadly cannot opt for this route.

Comment: Have you considered generating the Excel document on the server side, perhaps using [Open Office XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)(my personal favorite)? Export the underlying data, not the HTML table.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into both of these options. Do you know if what we're trying to accomplish is possible on client-side?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, just about anything is. Whether there's an existing client side non-Flash based solution out there I'm kind of doubtful of. Usually generating binary documents is done on the server side.